# Optimal assignment of values in for loop to vector

Tags: r

I have written code to generate a sequence of values `A01, A02, A03, A04, A05, B01, B02, ..., G04, G05.`  I know that in R we usually don't like to use for loops.  This code works, but is it the best way to handle this problem?

```
letters <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G")
numbers <- c(1:5)
l <- vector()
count <- 1
for(i in letters)
{
    for(j in numbers)
    {
        l[count] <- paste(i, j, sep="")
        count <- count + 1
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The aversion to loops in R is somewhat overdone.  If you aren't working with excessively large data or complex analyses, and don't need to create performance code, you can use a loop.  The potential advantage of a loop is that they are easy to write without making mistakes and it's easy to see how your code works when you come back to it later.  Loops 'clash' somewhat with the way R works under the hood, but for beginners it isn't really that big a deal.  You can use a loop for this, if that's what you're comfortable with.

On the other hand, I wouldn't do it this way.  Here is a way that isn't too advanced and yields cleaner code (see [?outer](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/outer.html)):

```
l <- outer(LETTERS[1:7], as.character(c(1:5)), FUN=paste, sep="")
l <- as.vector(l)
l
#  [1] "A1" "B1" "C1" "D1" "E1" "F1" "G1" "A2" "B2" "C2" "D2" "E2" "F2" "G2" "A3"
# [16] "B3" "C3" "D3" "E3" "F3" "G3" "A4" "B4" "C4" "D4" "E4" "F4" "G4" "A5" "B5"
# [31] "C5" "D5" "E5" "F5" "G5"
```

Comment: I'd add that loops tend to require explicitly assigning objects to variables whereas functions like `outer` and `apply` take care of that for you. This often leads to cleaner, more readable code (where efficiency is a nice bonus). It can, however, lead to _ambiguous_ code, which can make debugging harder or, even worse, silently produce incorrect results.